# Change future password value by one letter

Tags: sql, oracle

Im trying to somehow change passwords for database user schemas. This code will give me all schemas with password complexity i would like to start with :

```
SELECT 'alter user '||username||' identified by zsKtr3Prt5#45Yn;'
  FROM dba_users ;
```

Can i somehow iterate and change just *first* or *last letter* for each of them?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below script but needs to make sure that you do not have more than 25 users since it is using `CHR()` function -

```
SELECT 'alter user ' || username || ' identified by ' 
       || CHR(97 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY username)) ||'sKtr3Prt5#45Yn;'
  FROM dba_users;
```

Comment: Thank you for reply i have tested and it seems that i get desired results for first 29, other ones have the same string as password.

Comment: They are the non-printed characters I believe because It is not possible that function runs for few rows and not for others. I have already said you have to make sure that you have only 25 users. If you have more than that you need to mention that o=how you want to handle it. Should it again restart the characters?

Comment: My apologies, how to manage this for lets say 200 users?

Comment: It depends on how you want to keep the password for 27th user. Will it again repeat or some new character or they must start with number?

Comment: New character is ok, i wanted to have unique values

Comment: Then you can use it without passing 97 in the CHR function since we have 255 ASCII values.